# adding custom domain in heroku with big rock domain

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

I have a heroku app which i want to point to www.infoxpression.in

I added the domain name on heroku and added CNAME record in my bigrock DNS management but it is not working...

Big rock DNS management records:
[image]

Heroku dashboard:
[image]

Am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To connect your heroku hosting to big rock domain,

You have to open your big rock domain account and in the DNS Management page add in the cname the host: www and in the point to: your heroku url And in the heroku page in the settings add three domains:

1 *.xyz.com 
2: xyz.com
3. www.xyz.com

This is to point your domain name from heroku side

```
heroku domains:add example.com

heroku domains:add www.example.com

heroku domains:add *.example.com
```

This should work :) Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: does not work... What am I supposed to do with the dns targets provided by the heroku settings page when domain is added?

Comment: set them as the value of a CNAME record in your DNS control panel.

Comment: Put it in the cname. This will make it work Check this video for more help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Please see the updated images in the question and verify wether it is correct... it does not seem to work!

Comment: I think you're doing it right you have to wait less than 24 hours to see the result

Comment: Is there supposed to be any other record other than 'CNAME' like 'A' record? Currently I have only these 'CNAME' records

Comment: Why you have three different heroku domain names!

Comment: Write $heroku open then check the link that you have copy it and delete all the dns domains in heroku and type $heroku domains:add example.com
$heroku domains:add www.example.com
$heroku domains:add *.example.com and in big rock account cname just add one example.com and the value will be heroku url

Comment: This youtube will help you youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&feature=youtu.be let me know if it does work

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your bigrock account has default nameservers
like in the image:

Domain registration >> Name Servers

[image]

Do the domain forwarding as well.

Domain forwarding >> Manage domain forwarding >> add new

```
sub-domain prefix = (leave it blank if you have no subdomain)
destination URL = http://www.yourdoamin.com
URL masking is off
```

However, it will take 24-48 hours for updating.